# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in D:\node_e_modules\chart.js\package.json

Tags: next.js, chart.js, chartjs-plugin-zoom

When using chartjs-plugin-zoom(2.0.0) with chart.js(4.0.1) in Next.js getting this error - Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in D:\node_e_modules\chart.js\package.json

Comment: I think it's a bug. Maybe you can create an issue in github repo of zoom plugin.

Comment: I am getting the same error, is there any known solution or workaround?